# Calling contract method from already deployed contract

Tags: solidity, contract-invocation, contract-debugging

I have deployed a token contract, and now I want to use multiple transfers. I figured I can do this by deploying another contract which will run iteration over transfer function of my deployed token contract.

But I am getting failed transaction. I have run another test to clarify as well, below are the details:

**Deployed Contract Sample:**

```
contract MyToken {
    /* This creates an array with all balances */
    mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;

    /* Initializes contract with initial supply tokens to the creator of the contract */
    function MyToken(
        uint256 initialSupply
        ) {
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = initialSupply;              // Give the creator all initial tokens
    }

    /* Send coins */
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) {
        require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);           // Check if the sender has enough
        require(balanceOf[_to] + _value >= balanceOf[_to]); // Check for overflows
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;                    // Subtract from the sender
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;                           // Add the same to the recipient
    }
}
```

**Caller Contract Sample:**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;

contract MyToken {function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public; }

contract ADTest {

    function CallTransfer(address tokenAddress, address _to, uint256 _value) public {
        MyToken(tokenAddress).transfer(_to, _value);
    }

}
```

Can someone please help with the solution? I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

**UPDATE**
I figured If I send some tokens to the caller contract, then caller contract sends to different addresses, without any problem. Not sure weather its a suitable solution for now, but might will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this. Comments in-line.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;

// added I as naming convention (Interface)
contract MyTokenI {function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public; }

contract ADTest {

    // will hold an instance cast as type MyToken
    MyTokenI myToken;

    // pass the deployed MyToken address into this constructor
    function ADTest(address _myToken) public {
        // instantiate the deployed contract at _myToken
        myToken = MyTokenI(_myToken);
    }

    function CallTransfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public {
        // use the instance
        myToken.transfer(_to, _value);
    }

}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi @Rob Hitchens Thank you for the quick response, but I am still getting the same error, **Transaction Error. Exception thrown in contract code.
Gas limit set dangerously high. Approving this transaction is likely to fail.**

Answer (score 0):

Well, 1st you create `MyToken` with your user `0x1234` Then, address `0x1234...` calls  ADTest.CallTransfer(). `MyToken` deployed contract will check balance of `msg.sender`. But `msg.sender` is contract `ADTest`, not user "0x1234". So, `require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);` will fail and transaction will revert.

Here is my suggestion, using Rob´s suggestion also:

```
contract MyToken {
    /* This creates an array with all balances */
    mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;

    /* Initializes contract with initial supply tokens to the creator of the contract */
    function MyToken(
        uint256 initialSupply
        ) {
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = initialSupply;              // Give the creator all initial tokens
    }

    /* Send coins */
    function transfer(address sender, address _to, uint256 _value) {
        require(balanceOf[sender] >= _value);           // Check if the sender has enough
        require(balanceOf[_to] + _value >= balanceOf[_to]); // Check for overflows
        balanceOf[sender] -= _value;                    // Subtract from the sender
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;                           // Add the same to the recipient
    }
}

contract MyTokenI {function transfer(address sender, address _to, uint256 _value) public; }

contract ADTest {

    // will hold an instance cast as type MyToken
    MyTokenI myToken;

    // pass the deployed MyToken address into this constructor
    function ADTest(address _myToken) public {
        // instantiate the deployed contract at _myToken
        myToken = MyTokenI(_myToken);
    }

    function CallTransfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public {
        // use the instance
        myToken.transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi @luiz, I am looking for solution for a deployed contract, but this solution will require me to change signature of already deployed contract. Which I cannot do.

Comment: Well, in that case, only who deployed  ```MyToken``` will be able to transfer because of this require:  ```balanceOf[msg.sender] = initialSupply; ```